# Mount Triglav in June: accommodation opportunities

Tags: accommodation, weather-and-climate, mountains, alps, slovenia

Calling all Slovenia experts. I will climb the Triglav mountain from Krma on june 15th:
https://www.summitpost.org/krma-valley-via-kredarica/809427

However, it seems that all the huts on the way are closed in june even though there is different information from different site. Can anyone tell me if I have accommodation opportunities along the way?

Comment: Think about why they are closed - You might find the mountain unaccessible because of snow. June could be too early (happened to me twice)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual time period for taking on Triglav is during summer or fall. Experienced mountaineers may also do this in winter conditions. For those, the hut on Kredarica (Triglavski dom na Kredarici - 2515 m), while officially closed, provides basic lodging. You get a blanket, bed in unheated quarters and that's about it. The service is provided by a group of meteorologists that occupy the Kredarica station throughout the year.

The huts around Triglav usually open officially in June/July, depending on conditions. For Triglavski dom na Kredarici specifically, its [official website](https://www.pd-ljmatica.si/koce/kredarica/) claims that they will start accepting reservations for 2022 on June 27th (at time of writing).

The Alpine association of Slovenia [website](https://en.pzs.si) provides reliable information on mountain/hiking trails across Slovenia. You can find information about Slovenian huts on their sub-site [here](https://en.pzs.si/koce.php). The sub-site for Triglavski dom na Kredarici may be found [here](https://en.pzs.si/koce.php?pid=24) - [Slovenian version](https://www.pzs.si/koce.php?pid=24) provides more information (use translate).

Note: the route description you stated in your question is rather sketchy (obviously written by an experienced mountaineer in a hurry). At the very least, a map of the route would be expected. Perhaps check [this site](https://www.hike.uno/mountain/triglav/1/1) for more detailed route information (there are several marked routes possible from Krma valley to Triglav). Again, the Slovenian version of the site contains more information, including maps and comments.

Comment: Thank you very much! Useful information. Can you tell me if this place also will be open for sleeping June 16th? I have sent an email but no response
https://www.pd-ljmatica.si/koce/kamniska-bistrica/

Comment: @Avrgjooee, Dom v Kamniški Bistrici should be open on the 16th (Thursday). Their website says they are currently open Thursday - Sunday only. Might be best to call them anyway. Slovenia's international code is `+386`, so `+386 40 six20 78seven`. English shouldn't be a problem.